# What is the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP protocol?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I work for a consultancy. Over the past 10 years we have developed and deployed dozens of applications, many of which use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I received a message saying that some APIs will be discontinued on June 20th and I want to make sure I understand what they mean by this. All of my applications are Java-based servers that send notifications to Android apps, and all of them are using an HTTP post to do so (in other words, not using any kind of SDK or platform provided by Firebase).

The most recent of our projects are using a URL that looks like this:
[https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{our-project-name}/messages:send](https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7Bour-project-name%7D/messages:send)

Some older projects are using:
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Do either or both of these need to be updated?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: What I said about not using SDKs isn't totally correct. We are using a class called GoogleCredentials, from com.google.auth.oauth2, in order to get an access token to authenticate the newer requests. The older ones use a static API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy FCM API was deprecated last June 2023 and will be removed on June 2024 per the [latest migration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) guide. With this, you should migrate to FCM HTTP v1 API before the said deadline.

- Legacy API - https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
- HTTP v1 API - [https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project-name}/messages:send](https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7Bproject-name%7D/messages:send)